# Drive letters messed up in Windows 7. How do I get my drive letter back?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

After Windows failed to recognize a USB device (a hub) my drive letters got messed up. Because the hub had drives `J`, `K` and `L` connected these letters inadvertently became available, and when I put a USB stick in a different slot it became drive `J`.
Rebooted to get my `J`, `K` and `L` back. But now they were assigned `K`, `L` and `M`. `J` is not available when I try to rename `K` to that. How can I get an unused drive letter back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **To change, add, or remove a drive letter**
>
> 1. Open Computer Management by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>      Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security,
>      clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Computer
>      Management.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for
>      an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
>      provide confirmation.
> 2. In the left pane, click Disk Management.
> 3. Right-click the drive that you want to change, and then click Change
>      Drive Letter and Paths.
> 4. Do one of the following:
>
> *a. To assign a drive letter if one has not already been assigned, click
>   Add, click the letter that you want to use, and then click OK.*
>
> *b. To change a drive letter, click Change, click Assign the following
>   drive letter, click the letter that you want to use, and then click
>   OK.*
>
> *c. To remove a drive letter, click Remove, and then click Yes to confirm
>   that you want to remove it.*

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I'm aware of the procedure, it's just that I had overlooked that the `J` was assigned to an unconnected(!) removable device. Thanks for the answer, anyway.